# MongoDB Version 3.2.17 Sharded Cluster Stop Balancer

Tags: mongodb

Shard Cluster ( 3 Shards, Each Shard has 3 Nodes replica set)
Config Server is also Replica Set.

In our backup script, balancer is stopped. We are seeing following messages and not sure whether this is normal.

Ping shows old date ( recognize new settings )
a migration may be in progress or the host may be down

```
Stopping Balancer ....
Waiting for active hosts...
Waiting for active host node-mongo3-3:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Sat Sep 04 2021 15:53:14 GMT+0000 (GMT))
Waited for active ping to change for host node-mongo3-3:27017, a migration may be in progress or the host may be down.
Waiting for active host node-mongo2-3:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Mon Oct 18 2021 09:05:00 GMT+0000 (GMT))
Waiting for active host node-mongo1-3:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Tue Aug 31 2021 15:28:27 GMT+0000 (GMT))
Waited for active ping to change for host node-mongo1-3:27017, a migration may be in progress or the host may be down.
Waiting for the balancer lock...
Waiting again for active hosts after balancer is off...
Waiting for active host node-mongo3-3:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Sat Sep 04 2021 15:53:14 GMT+0000 (GMT))
Waited for active ping to change for host node-mongo3-3:27017, a migration may be in progress or the host may be down.
Waiting for active host node-mongo1-3:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Tue Aug 31 2021 15:28:27 GMT+0000 (GMT))
Waited for active ping to change for host node-mongo1-3:27017, a migration may be in progress or the host may be down.
Warning : host node-mongo3-3:27017 seems to have been offline since Sat Sep 04 2021 15:53:14 GMT+0000 (GMT)
Warning : host node-mongo1-3:27017 seems to have been offline since Tue Aug 31 2021 15:28:27 GMT+0000 (GMT)
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
Checking if the balancer is stopped
Balancer is not running now.
---------

    In config mongos setting ( I can see old ping date too)
    
    db.mongos.find()
    { "_id" : "node-mongo3-3:27017", "mongoVersion" : "3.2.17", "ping" : ISODate("2021-09-04T15:53:14.436Z"), "up" : NumberLong(17679988), "waiting" : false }
    { "_id" : "node-mongo2-3:27017", "mongoVersion" : "3.2.17", "ping" : ISODate("2021-10-25T19:15:04.779Z"), "up" : NumberLong(22098498), "waiting" : true }
    { "_id" : "node-mongo1-3:27017", "mongoVersion" : "3.2.17", "ping" : ISODate("2021-08-31T15:28:27.695Z"), "up" : NumberLong(17330247), "waiting" : false }

rs.printReplicationInfo()  
configured oplog size:   9775.30859375MB
log length start to end: 15014162secs (4170.6hrs)
oplog first event time:  Wed May 05 2021 23:42:53 GMT+0000 (GMT)
oplog last event time:   Tue Oct 26 2021 18:18:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
now:                     Tue Oct 26 2021 18:18:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
CR2ConfigRepSet_Prod:SECONDARY> rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()  
source: node-mongo3-3.mydomain.com:27019
    syncedTo: Tue Oct 26 2021 18:19:11 GMT+0000 (GMT)
    0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary 
source: node-mongo1-3.mydomain.com:27019
    syncedTo: Tue Oct 26 2021 18:19:11 GMT+0000 (GMT)
    0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary 
source: node-mongo3-504.mydomain.com:27019
    syncedTo: Tue Oct 26 2021 18:19:11 GMT+0000 (GMT)
    0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these commands:

```
rs.status() (run on mongos)
rs.printSecondaryReplicationInfo() (run on mongod replica set)
```

Instead of stopping the balancer by script, you may set [active window](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/schedule-backup-window-for-sharded-clusters/) for the Balancer.

```
db.getSiblingDB("config").settings.updateOne(
      { _id: "balancer" },
      {
         $set: {
            activeWindow: { start: "02:30", stop: "01:45" },
            attemptToBalanceJumboChunks: true
         }
      },
      { upsert: true }
   )
}
```

Comment: Updated results in question itself. I want to know whether there is some issue or it is just reporting issue. db.mongos.find does not show domain name e.g. "_id" : "node-mongo3-3:27017" i.e. No domain name here. Is that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved after I bounced router mongo service on all nodes with router service running.

It is also faster to stop/start balancer.

```
Stopping Balancer ....
Waiting for active hosts...
Waiting for the balancer lock...
Waiting again for active hosts after balancer is off...
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
Checking if the balancer is stopped
```